# What belongs in django model clean method

Tags: django, django-models

I'm wondering what the appropriate things to put in my model's clean() method are.

Does it make sense to put all the verification of and manipulation to a model's properties to ensure it is valid (ie. business logic)? There is a lot of that in my case and I'm wondering if it makes sense to execute it all every time a model is saved.

For example i'm doing things like :
- if a video is marked as private, remove all its references in playlsts
- ensure that the video's title is unique with relation to the users other videos
- etc.

some of the things i'm doing only really need to be done on creation of a new video - so checking/ setting them every time the model is saved also seems excessive.

Is this the correct use of the clean() method?

Comment: I dont think its too excessive. Data cant be clean(ed) enough ;), especiallly if its user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearing relationships is probably best handled by a signal. To validate your signals are working properly, you can write a unit test.

Validating that the title is unique is something that definitely belongs in a form/model validator. To me, that seems like a better separation of concerns.